# Does my computer/user profile need this many NTUSER.DAT files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems, user-accounts, user-profiles

What purpose does the following files serve?

[image]

Comment: You do understand, that you only have a single NTUSER.DAT file, right?  The other files are **not** NTUSER.DAT files, at least one of those files, is a .log file.

Comment: So I modified your question, and included an *actual* question in the body of your question, since you didn't provide one.  If you don't agree with the question I came up with, feel free to edit it, because a question body without an actual question isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

The .regtrans-ms files are registry transaction files, basically Windows wrote these out before committing the transaction to the actual registry, and as Ramhound mentioned in the comments, these are not NTUSER.DAT files. You only have one of those.

The .TM.blf file also has to do with the registry, though I'm not sure the exact nature of that file.

Comment: BLF stands for Binary Logging Format. For more information, dig into Common Log File System.